# Show currency symbol independent from device's Language

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

In an app I want to show the same amount of money in each user's localized currency.
The problem is that in `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`, it shows that the currency symbol is tied to the language of the device.

For the Norwegian Krone for example:
locale with identifier "**en_NO**" gives currency symbol "**NOK**"
but locale with identifier "**se_NO**" gives currency symbol "**kr**"

I want the user with region set as Norway to see the "kr" symbol, even when his currentLocale language is not swedish.

Is there any way around that?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue. The App Store shows prices as "22,00 kr", but using the locale and amount I get from `SKProduct` I get "NOK 22,00". This is on device.

Comment: I have noticed that even Apple's apps shows "NOK 22.00" - so I don't think there is any robust work-around.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the people using not Swedish see the symbol the same with the people using Swedish.

But the currency symbol is fetch with function

```
locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: code)
```

which means in different language, the symbol is different, so if you want the all users to see a specific symbol, you should bound the symbol with a specific language.

Not sure that's a good idea, but you can make a Swedish locale, and get a Swedish symbol with

```
NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "se_NO").displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: code)
```

Comment: I'm asking in general, not for Swedish in particular. I agree it's not a good idea, I will make some tests and see how I can use that.

Comment: @Vrasidas Did you solve your issue - or find a working solution?

Comment: @Johan It's been too long now, but I think for my case I did what ian suggested (I needed it for 3-4 locales only fortunately)